# Input value on a form not showing HTML WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, forms

I am working on a website and for some reason the input value is not working. It was just working about an hour ago and have made no changes to the site since then. For example: https://www.albright.edu/about-albright/offices-departments/registrar/transcript-requests/ at the bottom of that page, there are two buttons. One is for submit and one is for clear. Neither are showing the "value" part of the input so they both look blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a plugin in your theme ( maybe AutoOptimize) that's causing the color of the button to be transparent.

```
input[value] {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Try setting the color on your css.

Comment: Ahhh perfect, no idea why that is there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element with developer tools the text is present but the color is set to transparent (apparently from the plugin autoptimize).

You could try to use

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

or style these inputs with a custom class to set the color of the text

I hope this helps